# Finding the Min value for a subgroup, filtering out preceding Min values within the same parent group

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

How do I get the minimum value for a group (Acc, TranType), but filtering out any minimum values used in preceding rows for the Acc group. Preceding rows would be defined as Acc asc, TranType asc.

The PosCancelID should only appear once per Acc group. But the same PosCancelID could appear within another Acc Group within the data set.

So with the given data set:

```
Acc  | TranType | PosCancelID
100     1               2
808     1               5
808     1               4
808     2               5
808     2               4<--To be filtered from min calc as it min for (808,1)
813     2               3
813     4               3<--To be filtered from min calc as it min for (813,2)
809     1               3
809     1               4
809     2               3<--To be filtered from min calc as (809,1) uses it
809     2               4 
809     3               4<--To be filtered from min calc as (809,2) uses it
```

I should get:

```
Acc  | TranType | PosCancelID
100     1               2
808     1               4
808     2               5
813     2               3
809     1               3
809     2               4

SELECT ACC, TranType, min(maxPreceeding) as ActualCancelID 
FROM 
(
   SELECT ACC, TranType,  
          MAX(m.posCancelID) OVER (PARTITION BY m.ACC 
                                  ORDER BY m.TranType, m.posCancelID 
                                  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as maxPreceeding
    FROM MCancel as m
) AS x
GROUP BY ACC, TranType
```

The above query gives me almost what i want but isn't filtering for acc = 813. So I know there must be a better (actually applying a filter to remove previous minimum values) way.

Comment: Min values of one group cannot be the minimin value of the previous o cannot be the min of any other previous group?

Comment: I think my edit might have answered this. Min Value within Acc Group can only appear once but could appear within another Acc Group

Comment: Then an individual value used in previous (same) AccGroup and even if it is not the minimum of the previous group, must be avoided?

Comment: Hey @IDonaldson, I took the liberty of rewording your title as "less selective group" didn't seem to me to convey your intent clearly enough. Hopefully I didn't make the matters more confusing instead. Feel free to roll back my changes if you disagree.

Comment: @McNets the min filter only looks within the same acc group

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite a hard problem. Here is a recursive solution:

```
WITH 
  rcte AS
  ( SELECT TOP (1)
        Acc, TranType, posCancelID,
        CAST('=' + CAST(posCancelID AS VARCHAR(20)) + '=' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS IDs 
    FROM
        MCancel
    ORDER BY
        Acc, TranType, posCancelID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Acc, TranType, posCancelID,
        CAST(IDs + CAST(posCancelID AS VARCHAR(20)) + '=' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM 
      ( SELECT
            m.*, 
            r.IDs, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m.Acc, m. TranType, m.PosCancelID) AS rn
        FROM
            rcte AS r 
            JOIN MCancel AS m
                ON  (m.Acc = r.Acc AND m.TranType > r.TranType)
                OR  (m.Acc > r.Acc)
        WHERE
            r.IDs NOT LIKE ('%=' + CAST(m.posCancelID AS VARCHAR(20)) + '=%')
      ) AS mc
    WHERE
        rn = 1
  )
SELECT Acc, TranType, posCancelID
FROM rcte
ORDER BY Acc, TranType ;
```

The solution assumes that a `posCancelID` should not appear twice in the result set. If the requirements are that they should not appear twice  **in the same `Acc` group**, then the solution needs a slight adjustment:

---

```
WITH rcte AS
  ( SELECT 
      Acc, TranType, posCancelID,
      CAST('=' + CAST(posCancelID AS VARCHAR(20)) + '=' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS IDs 
    FROM
      ( SELECT 
          Acc, TranType, posCancelID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Acc ORDER BY TranType, PosCancelID) AS rnk
        FROM MCancel
      ) AS f
    WHERE rnk = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      Acc, TranType, posCancelID,
      CAST(IDs + CAST(posCancelID AS VARCHAR(20)) + '=' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM
      ( SELECT
          m.*, r.IDs, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.Acc
                             ORDER BY m.TranType, m.PosCancelID) AS rn
        FROM
          rcte AS r 
          JOIN MCancel AS m
              ON  (m.Acc = r.Acc AND m.TranType > r.TranType)
        WHERE
          r.IDs NOT LIKE ('%=' + CAST(m.posCancelID AS VARCHAR(20)) + '=%')
      ) AS mc
    WHERE rn = 1
  )
SELECT Acc, TranType, posCancelID
FROM rcte
ORDER BY Acc, TranType ;
```

Both are tested at **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5d4a357bf1893945316a0e25875e5a06)**

Comment: Thanks you second query is what i needed, as i needed In Same Acc Group.

Answer (score 3):

Using a CURSOR:

This solution uses a temporary table to store each calculation of minim value and filtering next one using data stored in this temporary table for the previous Acc values.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    Acc int, 
    TranType int, 
    PosCancelID int
);
GO
```

```
DECLARE @acc int, 
        @trantype int, 
        @poscancelid int;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT   Acc, TranType
    FROM     MCancel
    GROUP BY Acc, TranType
    ORDER BY Acc, TranType;

OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @acc, @trantype;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO #tmp
   SELECT Acc, TranType, MIN(PosCancelID)
   FROM   MCancel
   WHERE  Acc = @acc
          AND TranType = @trantype
          -- filter any previous min value for same Acc
          AND PosCancelID NOT IN (SELECT PosCancelID 
                                  FROM #tmp
                                  WHERE Acc = MCancel.Acc)

   GROUP BY Acc, TranType;

   FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @acc, @trantype;

END 

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

```
SELECT * FROM #tmp;

Acc | TranType | PosCancelID
--: | -------: | ----------:
100 |        1 |           2
808 |        1 |           4
808 |        2 |           5
813 |        2 |           3
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9092c2921667bdfadd9665f43b7f6ba5)*

Answer (score 0):

It could probably be improved for performance but I was able to get the result by ranking over multiple groups of the data.

First, it finds the minimum within the group (Acc, TranType) defined as PosMin.
Then, it will generate two sets of rankings. 
One for the set over (Acc, PosMin) as RankAcc. 
A second for ranking within (Acc, TranType, PosMin) as RankAccTran.

When they are the same, the record is either the minimum and the first instance of the minimum within the (Acc) group or they are the not the minimum but within a different (TranType) in the (Acc) group.

Evaluating the rankings to be equal gives you the records that meet both the requirement to be the first minimum within the Acc but also the minimum within the Acc,TranType group.

```
SELECT Acc, Trantype, PosCancelID
FROM (SELECT Acc, Trantype, PosCancelID, 
          dense_rank() over(    PARTITION BY acc, PosMin 
                                ORDER BY acc, trantype) RankAcc, 
          rank() over(  PARTITION BY acc, trantype, PosMin 
                        ORDER BY acc, trantype, poscancelid) RankAccTran
          FROM (SELECT Acc,TranType, PosCancelID, MIN(PosCancelId) over(PARTITION BY acc,
                     trantype) AS PosMin
                    FROM mCancel m
               )
          m2
     )
m3
WHERE RankAcc = RankAccTran
ORDER BY acc, trantype;
```

Comment: See the results for another dataset: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=50057ca222b23d473d137498d7726d78

Comment: Does it show wrong for another dataset? I thought within each TranType group, it needs only the minimum but within the Acc group overall, it only wants the first minimum.

Comment: It shows the same `PosCancelID` for 2 groups (for that dataset, above). For the original dataset, it works ok.

Comment: Neither of the two same `PosCancelID` being repeated are the minimum though. The minimum across the `Acc` is 1 in your dataset. He didn't define what he wants to do with other values in the `TranType` group which aren't the minimum.

Comment: I assumed that when the OP says "minimum", they  mean the minimum as calculated with their requirements. Lets wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Sorry for my poor question causing confusion. Within a Acc Group if the PosCancelID has been used then that row should be filtered from further Minimum calculations. So using yper-crazy-cube's filddle this should give a resultset of: `(100 1 1),(100, 2,2) (100,3,3)`

Answer (score 0):

A more procedural approach inspired by McNets and ypercube solutions worked for me:

```
--Optional setup code
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mCancel
GO

CREATE TABLE mCancel (
    rowId           INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Acc             INT NOT NULL,
    TranType        INT NOT NULL,
    PosCancelID     INT NOT NULL,
    notes           VARCHAR(100) NULL
)
GO

-- Mix up the two test sets
INSERT INTO mCancel
VALUES
    ( 100, 1, 1, '' ),
    ( 100, 2, 1, '?' ),
    ( 100, 2, 2, '' ),
    ( 100, 3, 2, '?' ),
    ( 100, 3, 3, '' ),

    ( 808, 1, 5, '?' ),
    ( 808, 1, 4, '' ),
    ( 808, 2, 5, '' ),
    ( 808, 2, 4, '<--To be filtered from min calc as it min for (808,1)' ),
    ( 813, 2, 3, '' ),
    ( 813, 4, 3, '<--To be filtered from min calc as it min for (813,2)' ),
    ( 809, 1, 3, '' ),
    ( 809, 1, 4, '?' ),
    ( 809, 2, 3, '<--To be filtered from min calc as (809,1) uses it' ),
    ( 809, 2, 4, ''  ),
    ( 809, 3, 4, '<--To be filtered from min calc as (809,2) uses it' )
```

Main code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- More procedural approach; known loops
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #working

CREATE TABLE #tmp1
(
    Acc         INT NOT NULL, 
    TranType    INT NOT NULL, 
    PosCancelID INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ( Acc, TranType, PosCancelID )
);

CREATE TABLE #working
(
    Acc         INT NOT NULL, 
    TranType    INT NOT NULL, 
    PosCancelID INT NOT NULL,
    xlevel      INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ( Acc, TranType )
);


-- Get working set
INSERT INTO #working
SELECT Acc, TranType, MIN(PosCancelID) PosCancelID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Acc ORDER BY TranType ) AS xlevel
FROM mCancel
GROUP BY Acc, TranType
ORDER BY Acc, TranType


-- Now add in NEXT min TranType + PosCancelID if it doesn't already exist
DECLARE @rowcount INT = -1, @i INT = 1
WHILE @rowcount != 0
BEGIN

    -- Put the level x ids into tmp
    INSERT INTO #tmp1
    SELECT m.Acc, m.TranType, MIN(m.PosCancelID)
    FROM mCancel m
        INNER JOIN #working w ON m.Acc = w.Acc
            AND m.TranType = w.TranType
    WHERE xlevel = @i
      AND NOT EXISTS
        ( 
        SELECT PosCancelID
        FROM #tmp1 t 
        WHERE w.Acc = t.Acc
          AND m.PosCancelID = t.PosCancelID
        )
    GROUP BY m.Acc, m.TranType

    SET @rowcount = @@rowcount
    SET @i += 1

    -- Loop safety
    IF @i > 999
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Too many loops! (%i)', 16, 1, @i )
        BREAK
    END

END

SELECT @i loops

SELECT TOP 100 *, CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM #tmp1 t WHERE m.Acc = t.Acc AND m.TranType = t.TranType AND m.PosCancelID = t.PosCancelID ) THEN '*' ELSE '' END x
FROM mCancel m
ORDER BY Acc, TranType, PosCancelID
GO
```

It's based on the data only having so many *levels* and working through these one at a time (in a similar way to the recursive CTE) but using set-based existence checks rather than string-based pattern matching to ensure the `PosCancelID` has not occurred before for the particular `Acc`.  At low volumes (eg uner 1,000 records) all the solutions complete in under a second, but scaling up to 1 million rows I started to see a difference, where the procedural approach performed better (using my [simple test rig](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/994f6439b50d1022b7af72d87a633b0e)).